# Omniture API break requesting to fast

Tags: php, adobe-analytics

Im using AdobeDigitalMarketing API (https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/marketing-cloud-php-sdk) for make API Calls to fetch Omniture data.

This script works ok:

```
   define('OMNITURE_USERNAME', 'XXX');
   define('OMNITURE_SECRET', 'XXX');
   define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));

   require_once(ROOT.'/lib/AdobeDigitalMarketing/Autoloader.php');
   AdobeDigitalMarketing_Autoloader::register();

   $adm = new AdobeDigitalMarketing_Client();
   $adm->authenticate(OMNITURE_USERNAME, OMNITURE_SECRET);

   echo $adm->getCompanyApi()->getEndpoint('Ford EU');

   $reportApi = $adm->getReportApi();


   $response = $reportApi->queueRanked(array(
      'reportSuiteID' => 'fmeuesprod',
      'date'     => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 day")),
      'metrics'  => array(
          array('id' => 'instances'),
      ),
      'elements' => array(
          array('id' => 'prop11'),
      ),
      'segments' => array(
         array('id' => 'prop11', 'selected' => array('brand:vehicle:brochures:interactive'))
      ),
      'segment_id' => 'dw:80632'

   ));

   $reportId = $response['reportID'];
   //echo $reportId;

   //$reportId = '67854594';

   do {
       $report = $reportApi->getReport($reportId);
       sleep(2);
   } while ($report['status'] == 'not ready');

   print_r($report['report']);
```

But if i call some times, then return this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'AdobeDigitalMarketing_Api_ReportError' with message 'A system error has occurred' in /var/www/OmnitureAPI/lib/AdobeDigitalMarketing/Api/Report.php:202 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/OmnitureAPI/lib/AdobeDigitalMarketing/Api/Report.php(84): AdobeDigitalMarketing_Api_Report->returnResponse(Array) #1 /var/www/OmnitureAPI/test.php(43): AdobeDigitalMarketing_Api_Report->getReport(67856255) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/OmnitureAPI/lib/AdobeDigitalMarketing/Api/Report.php on line 202
```

If i wait about 5 minutes, and press F5, the script works, if press F5 again, return the error...
The documentation of the API dont show nothing about this isure, and i need to call this script with some diferent dates every time.

any idea to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have experience writing my own scripts that using Adobe's API directly, but I don't have any experience with the framework for it that you posted, so I don't have much help to offer, but.. the error isn't really that helpful from an API PoV because it isn't showing the actual error returned by Adobe. Since you say it works, but not if you do it too soon afterwards, my guess would be that there is a problem with the `Nonce` value generated for the request.

Comment: Basically, Adobe API is structured to expect a unique id for every request made by anyone, anywhere, ever. If there is a collision, the Adobe API will respond with an error.  TBH though, I think this is buggy on Adobe's end though, because usually I do something like `$companyName.'_'.$randomString.'_'.dechex(time())` for the `Nonce` and yet *still* I sometimes get that error.   But anyways, that's just my first guess, based on you mentioning how it works sometimes but other times not.

Comment: I would suggest as a first step, you update the code in the library to output the raw response from the Adobe API call so you can see what error message Adobe is actually returning.

Comment: @CrayonViolent -> The nonce is part of the WSSE user token, and is important when used with the current z time to protect against replay attacks should someone be able to break the SSL encryption at some later point. If you are seeing an error it is not because of that, we don't check for collisions, if the caller decides to make a less secure call we cannot totally stop them, I think you maybe correlating it with the cache buster url scheme we use for data collection. If you are seeing errors do post them and I will be happy to look.

Comment: @Zenth -> The way this script runs is that it makes the call and then enters a loop waiting on for the report to be ready. You should not need to rerun it unless the first call failed. The script should not be considered production ready, it is a starting point to begin using the APIs. you still need to manage the corner failure cases and log correctly. The script is older, there maybe a new one, but it uses the older 1.3 API which is documented here https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/sitecatalyst-reporting/c-overview-1

Comment: @ChrisdeGroot hmm interesting.. I don't remember offhand what the exact error msg is but i remember it saying something to the effect of "Nonce value already exists" or something.  I'll post it next time i see it

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem:

The API 1.3 its now "obsolete", if change the API before login, all work:

```
    $adm = new AdobeDigitalMarketing_Client();

    $adm->getHttpClient()->setOption('api_version', '1.4');

    $adm->authenticate(OMNITURE_USERNAME, OMNITURE_SECRET);
```

Thanks all for the help and comments!